# Eclipse Run Configuration - Working Directory for projects not in workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When I import a project from a local Git repository via EGit, Eclipse successfully creates the project and does not copy it into the workspace.

Everything works fine in Eclipse, but all of the launchers like "Run As..." have a default working directory of `${workspace_loc}/project_name`.  This is a problem because the project doesn't live there - it may not even be a folder.

This especially breaks external tool launches (e.g., `grails run-app`) that depend on the current working directory, but is also true for standard run configurations like Run Application and JUnit test - they all default to assume the working directory is the project name under the workspace, even if the actual project location is somewhere else.

So my real question is - why doesn't the current directory in Run Configurations default to `${project_loc}`?  Why does it assume that the working directory should be under the workspace when the actual project isn't?

This isn't really a Grails question or a Git question, as much as an Eclipse question.

I imagine I would have the same problem with importing any other existing project outside the workspace.

I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem, what kind of run configuration are you using (what type)?

Comment: Grails run-app - but other run configurations like "Java Application" seem to default to `${workspace_loc}/project_name` as well even if the actual project location is somewhere else. 

My point was, why does Eclipse always default to working directory, instead of the actual project location (`${project_loc}`)

Comment: "Java Application" run configurations default to `${workspace_loc:projectname}` here, which resolves to the project location. I'm using Kepler, maybe it was a bug in Juno?

Comment: @robinst - yes, they default to ${workspace_loc:projectname} which is NOT always the same as the project location since you can add projects outside the workspace without copying them.

Comment: I just tested this, and it works as expected here. Workspace is in `~/workspace`, the project is in `~/tmp/outside`. When running a simple main class in that project which prints the current directory, `~/tmp/outside` is printed.